# Composite component javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component "inputID" in view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component, mojarra

I have a composite component which works pretty well when used once in a page but doesn't work if I use it more than once. Let's say the component is called my:field:

```
    <composite:implementation>
            <h:form id="myForm" prependId="false">
                    <p:message for="inputID" display="text"/>
                    <p:inputText binding="#{myBean.valueBind}"  id="inputID" value="#{myBean.value}" required="true" />
                    <p:commandButton process="@form" update="@form" action="#myBean.action} value="Do something" ajax="true"/>
            </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
```

And I use it like this:

```
    <my:field id="field1"/>
```

That works fine, but if I add this below it:

```
    <my:field id="field2"/>
```

I get the following exception `javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component "inputID" in view.`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? I've tried prepending the form id, the component id (field1) by using `cc.attr.id`. I just don't know what I need to do.

I am using mojarra 2.1.13, and primefaces 3.5. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT: I added the `binding=....` attribute to my `p:inputText` as that is what is causing the issue but I had omitted it in my initial post.

Comment: Code posted so far works for me, so it's either incomplete, or you're not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: You are 100% right, my example here was simpler and untested. In an effort to move enough code from the one with the real issue into this example to see when it creates the problem I managed to discover the issue. I have a `binding` attribute on the `p:inputText`. If I take that out it works just fine. I guess it makes sense that two components can not bind to the same thing, I just wish the error would have made more sense. Thanks for pointing out this worked and getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the `binding` attribute. Removing it makes things work, I will just need a different way of invalidating that field.